# Use of JSF 2.0 with webcenter

Tags: jsf, webcenter

We would like to use JSF 2.0 application with webcenter application. In the current release, web center PS7 support JSF 1.2 only. Please let me know if anyone has come across such a situation.
We plan to use pure JSF 2.0 component which will be exposed as remote portlets.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet, you have to wait until WebCenter 12c get released!